# Crawling single pages with scrapy.Spider works but not for entire website with CrawlSpider

Tags: scrapy

Need some help here. My code is working when I am crawling one page via (scrapy.Spider). However once I switch to (CrawlSpider) to scrape the entire website, it does not seems to work at all.

```
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ['reifen.check24.de']
    start_urls = [
        'https://reifen.check24.de/pkw-sommerreifen/toyo-proxes-cf2-205-55r16-91h-2276003?label=ppc',
        'https://reifen.check24.de/pkw-sommerreifen/michelin-pilot-sport-4-205-55zr16-91w-213777?label=pc'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny= ('cart')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div[1]'):
            yield {
                'brand': quote.xpath('//tbody//tr[1]//td[2]//text()').get(),
                'pattern': quote.xpath('//tbody//tr[3]//td[2]//text()').get(),
                'size': quote.xpath('//tbody//tr[6]//td[2]//text()').get(),
                'RR': quote.xpath('div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span/div/div/div[1]/span/text()').get(),
                'WL': quote.xpath('div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span/div/div/div[2]/span/text()').get(),
                'noise': quote.xpath('div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span/div/div/div[3]/span/text()').get(),

            }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: parse function is reserved by CrawlSpider. So, you should change function name from parse to parse_item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a tiny mistake:

```
 rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny= ('cart')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
```

should be:

```
 rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny= ('cart')), callback='parse', follow=True),
    )
```